# How to play multiple mp3 files one after the other using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame and trying to write a script that plays multiple mp3 files and rotates through the directory every 30 seconds to a new mp3 file.

So far I've learned how to play a specific file by doing the following:

```
import pygame

file = 'EverythingInItsRightPlace.mp3'
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
```

Do I have to specify each file in my script? What can I do to make it play all mp3 files one after the other and go to the next after 30 seconds?

edit**

I was able to turn off the song after 30 seconds. But am still unsure how to change to a new song afterwards.

```
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): 
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(30000)
    if pygame.time.delay(30000):
        break
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nice choice of music!

to get all mp3 filenames:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("/mydirectory"):
    if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
        file = filename
```

now, after you play with the music with :

```
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

you can wait for 30 seconds of music playing to be 30 seconds by:

```
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): 
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(30000)
    # you can break out the loop and change the file to be played after this.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's finally playing the .mp3 files in the directory. How would I change the file to be played after? I've been trying out a few things on http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.get_time but still can't figure it out. Would I use delay in this case? If delay then play next file?

Comment: in essence, i think you need to wait for 30 seconds, stop the current mp3 from playing, load a new file, and play the new file.

in more detail: how to do that depends what else you're doing in your code.  i think delay() works, and when delay over, stop the mp3 from playing, and load the next one. However i think delay() blocks execution. so if you want to do something else concurrently, you can keep tracking the time while doing something else, and when it is beyond 30seconds, then handle the loading of the next mp3